# What "written word" is Cletus Kasady referring to?

Tags: venom

In *Venom Let There Be Carnage* (2021), Cletus Kasady meets Venom:

> Cletus Kasady: Do a man who's buried alive a kindness, won't you? Get
> a message out to all my...fans. And in return, I'll give you my
> life......story. I heard the **written word** hasn't been working out so
> well.

What "written word" is Cletus Kasady referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the start of the film we see Eddie... not coping well with his new status as the carrier of the Venom symbiote. He looks like reheated crap, he got dumped and his career has gone in the toilet.

Cletus is pointing out that journalism hasn't been good to Eddie of late, but that a big scoop might help to revive his career.

> **Reporter (voice-over):** *Bowing to public outrage, the governor of California has overturned his moratorium and reinstated the death penalty for Kasady. **Brock’s career has been given a much-needed revival**, putting him back on top once more.*